# How to use javabeans in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javabeans, servlet-3.0

I am using this book: http://pdf.coreservlets.com/Form-Data.pdf
and topic 4.7 is: **Automatically Populating Java Objects from Request Parameters: Form Beans** 
I am trying to implement the code using Eclipse but it is creating problems. I have tried two ways as following:

1. I created file `BeanUtilities.java` in the folder `\coreservlets\beans`.
2. I created file `BeanUtilities.java` in the folder `\coreservlets\src\coreservlets\beans`.

   - When I used the first method then in the file `SubmitInsuranceInfo.java` there was this error:

> BeanUtilities cannot be resolved

and there was no error in file `BeanUtilities.java`.

- But when I used the second method then in the file `BeanUtilities.java` it is giving this error:

> The import org.apache.commons cannot be resolved

and no error in file `SubmitInsuranceInfo.java`.

Can anyone please give me a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> BeanUtilities will not work unless you install the Jakarta Commons
>   BeanUtils. However, since BeanUtils depends on two other Jakarta
>   Commons components—Collections and Logging—you have to download and
>   install all three.

Download Jakarta Commons BeanUtilities, Collections and Logging jars from here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/ 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/

Add these jars to your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you imported the requires jar. In your pdf example also read the comment which help you more. On the code example in PDF it is already mention:

/** Some utilities to populate beans, usually based on
 * incoming request parameters. Requires three packages
 * from the Apache Commons library: beanutils, collections,
 * and logging. To obtain these packages, see
 * http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/. Also, the book's
 * source code archive (see http://www.coreservlets.com/)
*/

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put all those packages? I'm newbie!!

Comment: In your **lib** folder..see your eclipse project structure. copy the jar file and paste inside the eclipse's lib.

Answer (score 0):

> BeanUtilities cannot be resolved

--> In file `SubmitInsuranceInfo.java` must have:

```
import coreservlets.beans.BeanUtilities;
```

> The import org.apache.commons cannot be resolved

--> Import [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/). Down load from [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi)
(Need file: `commons-beanutils.jar`) add to your `Java Build Path` & `Deployment Assembly`.

In file `BeanUtilities.java` must have:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
```